# Node.js beginner tutorial script - Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: node.js, localhost

The question is about an issue with Node.js. I'm new to it, following a tutorial, and the tutorial's first Node script ran successfully on my system (Hello World). Now, I've copied and pasted the code from the second part of the tutorial (creating an http server) and attempted to connect to it on my localhost through port 8080, but my browser (Chrome) returned an error.

> Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

So, I'm not really sure what's wrong here. I would assume that I correctly installed Node, since my first script ran properly. Perhaps this is a simple beginner mistake, and I am missing it.

Here is the script:

```
// Include http module.
var http = require("http");

// Create the server. Function passed as parameter is called on every request made.
// request variable holds all request parameters
// response variable allows you to do anything with response sent to the client.
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    // Attach listener on end event.
    // This event is called when client sent all data and is waiting for response.
    request.on("end", function () {
        // Write headers to the response.
        // 200 is HTTP status code (this one means success)
        // Second parameter holds header fields in object
        // We are sending plain text, so Content-Type should be text/plain
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        // Send data and end response.
        response.end('Hello HTTP!');
    });
// Listen on the 8080 port.
}).listen(8080);
```

I saved this to a file, server.js, navigated to the proper directory in Command Prompt, and executed Node server.js with no errors.

What might the issue be?

Comment: What tutorial are you following?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/nodejs-for-beginners--net-26314 @HectorCorrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    console.log(request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.end('Hello HTTP!');

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: That solved it. Thank you, what was wrong with the tutorial script?

Comment: I honestly don't understand why the code in the tutorial does not work *unless* you add a handler for `request.on('data')` to it as shown in this other tutorial: http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-read-POST-data

Comment: If you look at the first comment on the tutorial link, the issue is explained nicely.